# Porto Darsena base entrance

Tags: just-cause-3

I get that Porto Darsena has a entrance on the top that will teleport you to another part of the map and that should be an Easter Egg.
The problem is, after entering that metal door+hole on the floor, the base is just not there. I'm sent to another place on the map.

Is that metal door the correct entrance to Porto Darsena base?
Or should I search for another entrance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metal door is not the correct entrance. Go down to the nearby bridge (which you cross in a Bavarium tank during a story mission), and follow the road back into the mountain. The base is entirely underground and it is pretty big.

Comment: I just found the entrance at the bridge! Thank you!